# Apply sorting to mysql table value stored like 9:15 AM,9:30 AM

Tags: mysql

Given the following format:

```
9:00 AM
9:15 AM
...
```

How can I sort a column in mySQL in descending or ascending order?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(time_coulmn,'%h:%i %p') ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless something silly has been done with the database, the data won't really be stored as a string in that form. Databases are good at storing date fields, and then sorting them when they return results; it's up to the application to work out how to display them.

If you're really storing the times as strings, the right thing to do is to stop, and change the way you're storing them. Store them as timestamps (`DateTime` in MySQL) , and then format them appropriately when you retrieve them.

Comment: what is wrong with `STR_TO_DATE` function in mysql?? Rather than a solution, your answer is erasing the question

Comment: For one, it means the sorting won't use an index (which it would if this were a native `datetime` field). For another, it confuses the display logic with the business logic. Formatting of times and dates is a display issue, not a data processing issue. Storing them as strings is one step away from storing numbers as strings and then converting them at read time.